# RHEL 7 "rpm", "yum" comment not found

Tags: installation, redhat-enterprise-linux, yum, rpm, packages

I have newly installed RHEL 7 and while trying to install some package I got error "yum command not found" and same for rpm as well.

Comment: https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2016/08/30/why-red-hats-new-dnf-package-manager-is-not-just-another-yum-2/

Comment: Are you `root`? Is `yum` in your `$PATH`? Try running the same command with `/usr/bin/yum` instead of just `yum`.